# how fix the issue that so that ubi-usersetup crash doesn't happen when I try to install ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, ubiquity, syslog

Whenever I try to install ubuntu 14.04 lts I get a message saying:

> ubi-usersetupcrash
>
> ubi-usersetup failed with exit code 10. Further information may be
>   found in var/log/syslog

What do I do so I can install ubuntu without it crashing?

Comment: Close-voters: This seems more likely to be due to corrupted installation media than a bug. It's probably a duplicate, but probably not off-topic. @user294547 If you select "Try Ubuntu" and then run the installer from the desktop (or Unity dash), then after the problem happens you can open a Nautilus (file browser) window and find the file `/var/log/syslog` to see what information is at/near the end of it. You could then add that to your question (by editing your question). That might help, but I do recommend [following Pabi's advice](http://askubuntu.com/a/488401/22949) first.

Answer (score 1):

This could just be a corrupted installation media.
You can try to burn a new installation cd / rewrite the installation stick.
If you want more input please post your syslog.

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problem during setup Ubuntu 14.04.1 (*ubi-partman failed with exit code 141*). The problem was with `dmraid`. There was `/dev/mapper/ddf1 on /dev/sda`. It caused the error in Ubuntu setup and in `sudo gparted`. It not solved with `sudo dmraid -E -r /dev/sda`, but `sudo apt-get purge dmraid` solved the error.